# Ionic app with IBM Mobile first 7.1 version

Tags: ionic-framework, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I am developing ionic app + Mobile first application .

First,I have worked with Mobile first platform 8.0 beta.It was successfully connected with mobile first server.

Now, I am trying with Mobile first 7.1 version(stable). I have installed mobile first 7.1 cli and I am able to see my installed version in my console.

By installing MFP Plugin "cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-mfp" .

After in my config.xml file mfp details added as following which is pointing to Mobile first 8.0,

```
plugin version: 8.0.00-20160328 

url:http://10.0.0.1:9080
```

How can I install the cordova mfp plugin for 7.1?

Any help will be appreciated!!!

Comment: if you failed to integrated Cordova  in the  mfp then let me know

Answer (score 1):

1. MobileFirst CLI contains an instance of Cordova CLI v5.0.0, Android platform version 3.6.4, and iOS platform version 3.7.0. It is not possible to upgrade or replace these embedded versions. Therefore, it is not a requirement for you to install Cordova on your developer workstation.
2. Only Android and iOS are supported for creating Cordova apps by using the MobileFirst CLI.

https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/hello-world/integrating-mfpf-sdk-in-cordova-applications/